# RestEasy CorsFilter for specific API URLs only

Tags: java, cors, jax-rs, resteasy

I'd like to set the resteasy cors filter up in the following way (I'm also using spring if it matters):

```
@Provider
@Component
public class CorsConfiguration implements Feature {

  @Override
  public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {

    CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter();
    corsFilter.getAllowedOrigins().add("*");
    context.register(corsFilter);
    return true;
  }

}
```

And it's working correctly. My issue is that I only want to enable CORS for certain APIs and I don't see any configuration in the CorsFilter class that talks about the URL. I am not asking about the allowed Origins, but rather the URL for which CORS should be allowed.

I tried creating an anonymous inner class but for some reason the whole thing stops working:

```
@Provider
@Component
public class CorsConfiguration implements Feature {

  @Override
  public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {

    CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter() {

      @Override
      protected void preflight(String origin, javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        //check requestContext URI info here..

        //call super method
        super.preflight(origin, requestContext);
      }
    };
    corsFilter.getAllowedOrigins().add("*");
    context.register(corsFilter);
    return true;
  }

}
```

I did manage to do what I want without using the resteasy CorsFilter class and instead define an @OPTIONS api endpoint for the URLs I want. But would like to know if it's possible to do it in the method mentioned above.

Thanks